# Why is JQuery not affecting tables in RMarkdown?

Tags: jquery, r, datatable, datatables, r-markdown

I'm trying to use JQuery on HTML tables in RMarkdown.
Specifically, I'm trying add row classes to certain rows of a DT::datatable using JQuery.

I've tested the jQuery code in jsFiddle and that works fine. I've also tested basic jQuery code (changing colour of headers) in RMarkdown. This also works. I've not managed to get jQuery relating to tables working on [DT::datatable](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) in RMarkdown.

The code below is from an .Rmd file.

```
# Test
```

```
{js jQuery codechunk}
// Test that jQuery works in Rmd
$('.h1').css('color', 'red')

// Updating classes does not work
$("tr:contains('Mazda')").addClass('Mazda');

// Colour styling also does not work
$("tr:contains('Mazda')").css("color", "red")
```

```
{r R codechunk}
library(DT)
  DT::datatable(mtcars)
```

I expect that when I inspect the table, the rows with "Mazda" will be coloured red and the  will have the class "Mazda".

I just see the plain DataTable, and the row classes are the standard ones.

Comment: Are you running this jquery code before the datatable is even drawn? I think this might be a timing problem.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was. However, I've just tried with calling the datatable first and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it! See section 2.9 of the [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/), "The `callback` argument."

I made the following changes and your code worked like a charm.

- Wrap everything you want to do inside a function.
- Call that function from the `callback` argument of `DT::datatable()`.
- (I did also change `.h1` to `h1` to make that part of the example work.)

Beautiful package by the way. Thanks for introducing me to it!

````
---
title: "It works!"
author: "trianglegirl"
date: "May 20, 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{js jQuery-codechunk}
const trianglegirl_function = function() {

  // Test that jQuery works in Rmd
  $('h1').css('color', 'red');

  // Updating classes does not work
  $("tr:contains('Mazda')").addClass('Mazda');

  // Colour styling also does not work
  $("tr:contains('Mazda')").css("color", "red");
};
```

```{r R-codechunk}
library(DT)
DT::datatable(mtcars, callback = JS('trianglegirl_function();'))
```
````

Comment: Thanks for this @Benjamin. Great to see that this works, however, I need to use the `datatable` function from the [DT package](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) - which creates an interactive, sortable JS table rather than `data.table::data.table`. Interesting to see that your code works for `data.table::data.table but not `DT::datatable`.

Comment: Amazing - thank you so much. So wrapping it in a function allowed it to be passed to DT. Awesome!